# Is it possible to use a Bitcoin hardware wallet with Tails?

Tags: tails, bitcoin

Is it possible to use a Bitcoin hardware wallet with the Electrum installed in Tails? It looks like there might be some libraries required for to access these devices over USB.

Comment: Yes, generally speaking: a USB device can be plugged to Tails VMs

Comment: I did a bit of research on this, it looks like these devices might require another library to work properly under Linux

Comment: so install it =)